# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC with SQLite in IIS 500 error code

Tags: sqlite, iis, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, ef-core-7.0

First use IIS. First time release to IIS is OK.

Adding Sqlite to VS compiles fine, but release to IIS results in an 500 error.

Nuget package: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 7.0.5

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004] An error occurred using the connection to database 'main' on server '|DataDirectory|\database.db'.

I edit to look like this :

```
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=d:\\www\\InProPlayerWeb\\InProPlayerWeb\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\publish\\database.db"
```

as same error

Permissions has added for everyone to execute, read, write

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\database.db"
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using InProPlayerWeb.Helper;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly PortHelper _portHelper;

    private readonly int areaCount = 20;
    private readonly int groupCount = 6;        
    private bool[] ZoneStatus = Enumerable.Repeat(false, 20).ToArray();

    public HomeController(PortHelper portHelper, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _portHelper = portHelper;
        _context = context;
            
        var configDB = _context.Configuration.ToList(); 

        _portHelper.PortName = configDB[0].PortName;
        _portHelper.BaudRate = configDB[0].BaudRate;
    }
}
```

If I edit it to look like this:

```
var configDB = _context.Configuration
//_portHelper.PortName = configDB[0].PortName;
//_portHelper.BaudRate = configDB[0].BaudRate;
```

then I get no error.

I'm not sure if connection to SQLite is successful ...

Comment: Start the compiled exe as a process using the command line. Then you can browse to localhost at port 5000 you can see the error.

Comment: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'main' on server '|DataDirectory|\\database.db'.

I edit to look like this :
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=d:\\www\\InProPlayerWeb\\InProPlayerWeb\\bin\\Release\\net6.0\\publish\\database.db"
as same 

Permissions has added for everyone to execute, read, write